# Java beginner - using the 'int counter' more than once within a button action

Tags: java, counter

I am a Java beginner and would like to know if I can use 'int counter' more than once as part of a button action. If I try to use this a second time I receive the error 'variable counter is already defined in method jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent)'. Is there a way of re-setting the counter so I can use it again for a different action?

Comment: `counter = 0`? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: just define it once and just use the variable name in any further steps.

Comment: I would recommend showing some code and the exact error you are receiving.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: You are probably saying `int counter` twice, which is *redefining* the variable. You should define it once as `int counter` and the use it as `counter`. [Check this out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the value you want when you want, but you can declare it only once:

```
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int counter = 0; // <-- declaration (and initialization)

        //do something with your variable

        counter = 0; //<-- Reset variable value. Declaration is not necessary now

        //do more stuff

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the button press defines the variable, after the first press the variable 'counter' will already exist, pressing again will attempt to create another variable called 'counter'.To resolve this create the 'counter' outside of the action performed, and refer to it when required.

Comment: *"Sounds like the button press defines the variable, after the first press the variable 'counter' will already exist, pressing again will attempt to create another variable called 'counter'."* This is wrong. OPs problem is not a single `int counter` with multiple button clicks. OPs problem is multiplie `int counter` in the same scope.